# E: Unable to locate package regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use the regex package in my python script, using:

```py
import regex as re
```

and the package is missing:

```
$ ./lula2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./lula2.py", line 13, in <module>
    import regex as re
ImportError: No module named regex
```

I'm trying to install it, and receive the following error/failure:

```
$ sudo apt install regex
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package regex

$ sudo apt install python-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

Please let me know how to install `regex`.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version is this? Also please add your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to the question.

Comment: Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 1):

`python-pip` and `python-regex` packages are in universe repository. Enable that using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
```

Then install `regex`:

```bsh
sudo apt install python-regex #For Python 2
sudo apt install python3-regex #For Python 3
```

If you want to install regex using pip:

- Install pip:

  ```bsh
  sudo apt install python-pip #For Python 2
  sudo apt install python3-pip #For Python 3
  ```
- And then regex:

  ```bsh
  pip install regex #For Python 2
  pip3 install regex #For Python 3
  ```